# Backups utility started requesting password again while syncing and not sure if sync is completing or not

Tags: backup, sync, cloud

Ubuntu 18.4

Bit of a fuzzy post here. About a week ago I set up the backups Utility that ships with Ubuntu with my cloud provider. Everything was going fine, I set it to daily and each day the utility would open and request my password, I would enter it, it would backup and then, if I recall correctly it would then just automatically close and all was well.

My home dir on this new os is about ~10GB and my cloud storage has 100GB total, it's not a space issue.

Now, a popup appears after sometime asking me to re-enter my password, which I do, and then it happens again a few minutes later.

Just now I tried to backup again manually by clicking 'back up now'. I entered my encryption password, it started backing up, then again:

[image]

If I press 'forward', which I presume to mean continue, it will just popup again in a few minutes.

There's no setting to delete and read the same cloud provider, I wanted to try to set up from scratch but this menu option doesn't exist.

How can I get my backups working again?

[Edit]

The back seems to work for a while today, for a couple of minutes before requesting my encryption password again. Even if I select 'remember password' it keeps asking for it. But logging into my cloud provider I can see that new encrypted files are being added, it seems that backup utility is unable to complete the back up without requesting my encryption password over and over.
[image]

Comment: Apparently, the backup utility is not anymore able to login using the provided credentials?

Comment: @vanadium that could be the case, but I haven't changed the passwords. In the backup utility I wanted to remove then re-add my cloud provider credentials but there's no option to do that

Comment: Also note my edit above